# index of an array is not recognized in awk

Tags: awk, associative-array

I have two tab separated files, each with two columns. I want to create a file which contains overlapping elements by column 1 of the two files. To do so, I put file 1 in an array first then scanned the array to check against file 2 for overlaps. However, somehow the index of the array cannot be recognized. See below for the elaboration of the problem.

The first 3 lines of the files look like this:

File 1:

```
90001   raw acceleration data
2634    Heavy DIY
1011    Light DIY
```

File 2:

```
2634    218263
25680   44313
25681   44313
```

To show that there are overlaps in column 1 of the two files:

```
user@cluster:~> grep 90001 file2
90001   103662
user@cluster:~> grep 2634 file2
2634    218263
```

To create file 3, I tried this first, which yielded an empty file.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"; OFS= "\t"} 
 NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
 { if($1 in a) print $1, a[$1]}' file1 file2 > file3
```

The following code confirmed the issue is the index of the array was not recognized; because adding the `else` line actually prints file2 into file3.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\t"; OFS= "\t"} 
 NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
 {if($1 in a) 
      print $1, a[$1]
   else 
      print $1, $2}' file1 file2 > file3
```

I am quite puzzled. I wonder what might have caused the issue and how I can fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `LC_ALL=C sed -n l file1 file2`? (`l` being lowercase `L`, not the digit 1)

Comment: Double check that there is actually a single literal tab character between the two fields on every line in the two files. I can not reproduce the issue locally with the files that you show (with tab as the delimiter).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. Here is the first line of the output
`90001\r\traw acceleration data$` I wonder what is `\r\t` doing there. Sorry I am not familiar with sed. Thanks.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry. I just edited the original post by copying and pasting the actual first 3 lines of the two files. Before the edit, I just typed in the entries to show what they look like...

Comment: @EdMorton Oh thanks! I did not realize`\r` is part of the field.

Comment: Is `r` for return?  I wonder how `r` got in there? I created file 1 with MS Excel, saving it as a tab delimited file.

Comment: `\r` is the `Carriage Return` character, see the reference I provided in my answer. I suspect you did more than just save it from XLS and that you re-ordered the fields after saving it or attached other strings to the end of it using a Unix tool since XLS would attach a `\r` to the **end** of each line, not the end of the first field in each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741298/index-of-an-array-is-not-recognized-in-awk/741309#comment1408394_741298):

> Here is the first line of the output `90001\r\traw acceleration data$`

your first field is `90001\r`, not `90001` so change `FS = "\t"` to `FS = "\r?\t"` to accommodate that `\r` in the input or add `{ sub(/\r/,"") }` or similar to the start of your script to remove it.

See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more info on `\r`s (Carriage Returns) in input files. They're usually at the end of lines rather mid-line though - your current problem is probably a result of some previous phase re-ordering the fields or attaching strings to the end of each line in a previous version of the file and not stripping the `\r`s then.

By the way, consider writing:

```
if($1 in a) 
      print $1, a[$1]
   else 
      print $1, $2
```

as a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator):

```
print $1, ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $2)
```

to avoid writing quite so much code and duplicating `print $1,`. Also consider changing this:

```
FS = "\t"; OFS= "\t"
```

to this:

```
FS=OFS="\t"
```

for the same reason - less duplication and more concise code.